# Expectation of a product of random variable : definition

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have an hard time to understand several things I see on the expectation of two random variables.

First, here is my definition of product of two real valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ :

$$
\mathbb{E}(XY) =\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)Y(\omega)d\mathbb{P} 
$$

But a lot of time I see double integrals appear when talking about this and I don’t see from where it comes.

Please if you have some insight tl provide don’t hésitate. A question like this has already been askeb but the answer did not help me.

Thank you a lot !

Comment: You rarely have random variables defined explicitly. If you only the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ you have to compute $E[XY]$ by computing a  double integral.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for the comment ! That is the point I am missing how the joint distribution (through wich arises the double integral) relates to the product of two random variables ? I mean, the joint distribution is the distribution of the random vector $(X,Y)$. In my integral I don’t have this but just the product of these two random variables ?

Comment: For any measurable function $f(X,Y)$ of $X$ and $Y$, we have $Ef(X,Y)=\int f(x,y) d\mu(x,y)$ where $\mu$ is the joint distribution . When $\mu$ has  density we can write $Ef(X,Y)=\int \int f(x,y)f_{X,Y} dxdy$.

Comment: @geetha290krm It is much clear now ! Consider $fX,Y) = XY$ was the key, took me a long time..  thank you a lot !